# Improve Efficiency Of This Query: Update With Joins and Subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with 
 
- table of Parcels which need to be sent to people (here 16,000 records), 
indexes on account_no, service
- table of Price Rates (500,000 records) - rate depends on: delivery area, customer price rate and type of service(e.g. next day etc), indexes 
on area, price rate, service
- table of first part of postcode (or zip Code), which gives area (3000)
- table of customer account, containing price rate (1600), index on price rate
The query finds the price it will cost to send the parcel and updates the customer price for that parcel with unique id
It is taking 70 seconds for 16000 parcel records to be updated with the price to send each parcel

```
UPDATE
   tbl_parcel AS t20, ( 
   SELECT 
      id, service, rate_group, area, 
      (
         SELECT
            rate 
         FROM
            tbl_rates_all t4 
         WHERE
            t4.service = t10.service 
            AND t4.area = t10.area 
            AND t4.rate_group = t10.rate_group 
      )
      AS price 
   FROM
      (
         SELECT
            id,
            t1.service,
            rate_group,
            area
         FROM
            tbl_parcel t1 
            JOIN
               tbl_account t2 
               ON t1.account_no = t2.account_no 
            JOIN
               tbl_pr_postcode t3 
               ON LEFT(full_pcode, locate(' ', full_pcode) - 1) = t3.postcode 
      ) t10 
) AS src 
   SET
      t20.customer_price = src.price 
   WHERE
      t20.id = src.id
```

Takes 70 seconds for the 16000 parcel records

Ultimately it is this part that is killing the efficiency
FROM
            tbl_rates_all t4 
         WHERE
            t4.service = t10.service 
            AND t4.area = t10.area 
            AND t4.rate_group = t10.rate_group

I could have separate rates tables for each rate as this was the original design so a variable would call e.g. tbl_rates001 which might only have 3000 records and not 500,000. Problem with doing this in mysql was when creating a table name on the fly it was not possible without using a prepared statement so i thought this method was no good. Shame you couldn't use a user variable to hold the price rate number and then add this to the table rate name.

I'm quite new to databases and queries so if something is screaming at you that would help then thanks for any input

regards

ADDTION AS REQUESTED SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_x_rate_all` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`service` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`chargetype` char(1) NOT NULL,
`area` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`rate` float(7,2) NOT NULL,
`rate_group` smallint(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `tbl_x_rate_all` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `rate_group` (`rate_group`), ADD KEY `area` (`area`), ADD KEY `service` (`service`),   
ADD KEY `chargetype` (`chargetype`);
```

Comment: Post your schema of tbl_rates_all including indexes.

Comment: thanks have done so

Comment: This is a killer too: `LEFT(full_pcode, locate(' ', full_pcode) - 1)`. In MySQL, functions cannot use indexes.

Comment: Hi strawberry. i did do away with that bit by creating partial postcode and indexing in parcel table, it didn't make that much difference but yes maybe 10 seconds less. thanks for your input!

Comment: I have no clue how your `price` subquery may be working, what's the point there? How can it reference t10, the outside alias from within? How is the subquery any different from simple `rate as Price`?

Comment: Hi Nae. If i create the t10 virtual table i then have the rate_group, area and service. From this i can use those in the rates_all table to get the price. sorry i think my naming is poor. rate(price) and rate_group could be easily confused

Comment: Also, my own experience has led me to generally favour uncorellated subqueries over corellated ones - but I appreciate that the choice of which to use when is really more subtle than that.

Comment: Hi Strawberry I've looked up corellated subqueries just now! So i'm right in saying that i'm in the uncorellated subquery park here(?) thanks!  I think i may have tried the other way(?) and the time was 5 mins+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `id`, `rate_group` and `area` are from `t1` inside `t10` then your query is a slower? version of the one below:

```
UPDATE
    tbl_parcel AS t20
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        t1.id,
        t4.rate as price
    FROM tbl_parcel t1
    JOIN tbl_account t2 ON t1.account_no = t2.account_no
    JOIN tbl_pr_postcode t3 ON LEFT(full_pcode, locate(' ', full_pcode) - 1) = t3.postcode
    LEFT JOIN tbl_rates_all t4 ON t1.service = t4.service AND t1.area = t4.area
        AND t1.rate_group = t4.rate_group
    ) src ON t20.id = src.id
SET
    t20.customer_price = src.price
WHERE
    t20.id = src.id
```

---

I am guessing you can further lose the subquery which tend to be cumbersome:

```
UPDATE
    tbl_parcel AS t20
INNER JOIN tbl_parcel t1 ON t20.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN tbl_account t2 ON t1.account_no = t2.account_no
INNER JOIN tbl_pr_postcode t3 ON LEFT(full_pcode, locate(' ', full_pcode) - 1) = t3.postcode
LEFT JOIN tbl_rates_all t4 ON t1.service = t4.service AND t1.area = t4.area
        AND t1.rate_group = t4.rate_group
SET
    t20.customer_price = t4.rate
WHERE
    t20.id = t1.id
    -- can also replace with
    -- TRUE
    -- or lose it altogether
;
```

---

You could try adding index on joins of `t1` and `t4` if you have reason to believe that the join is the bottleneck:

```
create index tbl_rates_all_service_area_rate_group_index
    on tbl_rates_all (service, area, rate_group);

create index tbl_parcel_service_area_rate_group_index
    on tbl_parcel (service, area, rate_group);
```

Comment: Hi Nae .. really appreciate the suggestion. I have given it a good test. On large numbers in the parcel table t1 e.g. 22000 both mine and yours are about 120 seconds. literally a second or 2 different. Yours always a second quicker. On small t1 parcel records e.g <1000 I mostly get yours being 1% quicker 7 seconds or so but also sometimes 10% quicker. Yours always quicker but mostly 1% quicker. what do you reckon. thanks again. Rich

Comment: @Rich If you still believe that the bottleneck is `t4` join, then try adding indexes to both `t1` and `t4` for joining columns in the order that they're joining.

Comment: Can you expand on "in the order that they're joining". I already have indexes on the join columns. Are you talking about creating temporary table with indexes? I tried your 2nd suggestion too but alas similar results. Good to see different ways it can be done though. thanks again

Comment: @Rich You can create a single index for multiple columns at once. In that case you may want to have a single index for `service`, `area` and `rate_group` on `t4` and then another single index for `service`, `area` and `rate_group` on `t1`.

Comment: ok thanks Nae.. i'll have a look at that and come back. ta Rich

Comment: thanks for everything Nae. At some point i'll try the multiple index joins. found i have a WHERE statement which i hadn't taken into account so i need to do a bit more work before i come back and try this out. regards rich

Answer (score 0):

@Rich --

Nothing's jumping out. You might be able to get some marginal improvements by building some temp tables, handling the `SET` outside your main query, and using some `OUTER APPLY` instead of the nested queries.

If you're fairly new to mysql / databases in general, the `EXPLAIN` function can be very useful in optimization

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Hi brian , thanks for your input so far! I will check the above out and come back to you